# Question regarding the definition of principal ideal

Tags: ring-theory, definition, ideals

So, according to definitions given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal left principal ideal is $\{ra:r\in R\}$, right principal ideal is $\{ar:r\in R\}$. Now, i was curious what the two sided ideal actually is, because the $\{r_1as_1+\ldots+r_nas_n:r_1,s_1,\ldots,r_n,s_n\in R\}$ really contrast with the two. The explanation is given that it is to ensure that the ideal (e.g. the subring) is closed under addition, now, what is the $n$ in the sum? Does that denote finite amount of elements in $R$ or if $R$ is infinite, then we simply take the double sum $\sum_i\sum_jr_ias_j$, or how should I actually grasp this? Thanks for explanation.

Comment: I think the following definition of the two sided ideal can be helpful: $\{r_1as_1+\cdots+r_nas_n| n\in \mathbb{N}\;s_ir_i\in R\} $.

Comment: So, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we take the finite sum up to $n$. So for $n=1$ it is just $ras$ for $r,s\in R$, then for $n=2$ it is $ras+paq$ for $r,s,p,q\in R$ and so on? Am i getting it right?

Comment: Yes you are. Every time you can write an element of the ring in such a way for some natural number $ n$ you can tell it is inside the ideal.